# How to set user and group in debian package using SBT Native Package?

Tags: debian, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a Scala/Play project where I use [SBT Native Packager Plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) **0.6.4** to create a debian package. By default all files are created using root user/group. How can I change it?

This is what I tried in `build.sbt`:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._

linuxPackageMappings in Debian <+= (version) map { (version) =>
  val tmp = IO.createTemporaryDirectory
  val tmpLog = tmp / "my-app" / "my-app.log"
  IO.write(tmpLog, "")
  packageMapping(tmpLog -> "/var/log/my-app/my-app.log") withUser "appuser" withGroup "appuser"
}

linuxPackageMappings <<= linuxPackageMappings map { mappings =>
  mappings map { linuxPackage =>
    linuxPackage.copy(
      fileData = linuxPackage.fileData.copy(
        user = "appuser",
        group = "appuser"
      )
    )
  }
}
```

However, in the resulting debian package (after running `sbt clean debian:package-bin`) all files are owned by `root`. User `appuser` exists on my system. It looks like SBT Native Packager ignores setting the user and the group both in specific as in general mappings.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was using version 0.6.4. Looks like upgrading to 0.8.0 fixed the issue.